# Searchable Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am learning android development. I was working around spinners. And I had to show the list of countries in spinner. Since the list is huge, it would be great to implement a search in the spinner. Any valuable inputs would be helpful to implement an own searchable spinner.

P.S.

1. I did research about the searchable option in spinner. And came across Searchable Spinner github library.(https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner).

Comment: If you are using it for country selection check this library [CountryCodePickerProjec](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject#:~:text=Country%20Code%20Picker%20(CCP)%20is%20an%20android%20library%20which%20provides,mask%20and%20international%20phone%20validation.)

Comment: @AgentP. Thanks for the reply. But, would like to know how to search some string in spinner.

Comment: Basically it's not a spinner it's just a list or recycler view that will be displayed based on filtration the adapter data set will be set.

Comment: May be https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView can help you to achieve similar functionality.